# Getting values from inner class in a method

Tags: java, lombok

I am trying to get the values of an inner class.
I believe I am doing this wrong because I am getting a null value.
Basically I wanted to get values of two hashsets. So I created a class to store those values and I have method to feed those values which returns the inner class.

```
outter class {
//some code

public myFunction(...){

//This method getAllResults should returns the class that have the sets stored
MyInnerClass allResult = getAllResults(resultSets);
Set<People> visiblePeople = allResult.visibleInfo;
 Set<People> allPeopleFromTable = allResult.allPeople;
}

//Using Lombok here
  @Data
    private class MyInnerClass {
        private Set<People> allPeople;
        private Set<People> visibleInfo;
    }

private MyInnerClass getAllResults(Foo resultSets) {

MyInnerClass inner = new MyInnerClass();
  
        for (Foo rs : resultSets) {
            while (rs.next()) {
                final Table people = new Table(rs);

                inner.allPeople.add(people);
                if (isVisible(people)) {
                    inner.visibleInfo.add(people);
                }
            }
        }
return inner;
}

}
```

Comment: Doesn't look like the sets are initialized.

Comment: I am using Lombok for the inner class https://projectlombok.org/features/Data for what I understand it automatically initialize

Comment: I doubt it. How would it know which implementation to use? [See also](https://github.com/projectlombok/lombok/issues/2390)

Comment: @pralxx please read the documentation you linked. It contains sample code "with lombok" and "without lombok". The "without lombok"-version shows that no initialization takes place. --- The post is missing a question and the code is not properly formatted. Please [edit] the post, format the code properly and add a focused question.

Comment: @shmosel you are right. I initialized the hashset in my method and then just use a setter because Lombok gives that. Thank you